# Problems with connection refused setting up ssh tunnel to aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to set up a raspberry pi to run on my desk and I'd like to remote into it from work via a tunnel. To do this I've setup an EC-2 instance that I'll use similar to ngrok to create tunnels to forward the ports on my pi to the aws server.

I think I've gotten everything set up correctly, and my pi says the tunnel has been created successfully, but when I try to connect to it with putty, it says that the connection was refused.

I've set up the aws server to allow all communication to and from all ports (temporarily) and I ensured that the `GatewayPorts` is set to `yes` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

I ran this command on my pi `ssh -i "./key.pem" -R 2222:127.0.0.1:22 -Nf ec2-user@ec2-instance.host`

Then I tried to log in from putty using the address `aaron@ec2-instance.host` with port `2222`, but it says the connection was refused?

I've also tried to use the user `ec2-user` instead when logging in, I'd assumed that wouldn't work, and I wasn't disappointed.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. Suggest you edit it to be clear what you're trying to achieve. Also, the question may be better on super user if it's not a business focused question. It seems you've chosen a really complex way to do this, you could consider Cloudflare Tunnel (search for it / Raspberry Pi tutorials) could be a lot simpler and is free.

Comment: this is how tunnel services do things, I'm doing it myself so that it's not hosted by somebody else, if it were possible, I'd cut aws out of the picture completely, but it's not possible for me to have a static public IP

Comment: I moved this to super user, because I believe you may be right: https://superuser.com/questions/1736066/problems-with-connection-refused-setting-up-ssh-tunnel-to-aws-ec2-instance